# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar Sublime Text mediante Git Bash?

Tags: git, bash, sublimetext3, git-commit

**Intenta corrigiendo la ruta**

```
echo 'alias subl="'C:\Program\ Files\Sublime\ Text\ 3\sublime_text.exe' "' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Luego escribí el comando siguiente para probarlo:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Y con esto ya podía abrir Sublime Text desde consola de la siguiente forma:

```
subl hola.txt
```

Para cargar este alias cada vez que iniciara la consola, creé un fichero `.bash_profile` y escribí las siguientes líneas:

```
if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
case "$-" in *i*) if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
```

Con esto he conseguido abrir Sublime Text desde consola, pero por alguna razón, cuando intento abrirlo mediante git, no me reconoce este comando. He probado escribir los siguientes comandos:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
git config --global push.default upstream
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Pero cuando escribo `git commit` sigue sin reconocer el comando `subl -n -w`, cuando yo sí lo ejecuto manualmente, sí que me funciona. He probado escribir la ruta directamente así:

```
git config --global core.editor 'C:\Program\ Files\Sublime\ Text\ 3\sublime_text.exe -n -w
```

Pero de esta forma me dice que el directorio no existe cuando sí que existe, porque manualmente sí que funciona.

Creía que sería problema del Sublime Text, así que instalé el Package Control y luego el paquete Git, pero sigue sin funcionarme.

Igual es una tontería, pero como soy muy novato en esto no sé qué puede estar pasando... ¿alguien sabe qué es lo que me falta?

Resumen:

```
subl hola.txt -> funciona
subl -n -w -> funciona
git commit -> no funciona
```

Comment: Solucionado, aquí he encontrado la respuesta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git

Comment: Ise92: podrías entonces publicar una respuesta con tu solución. [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta](/help/self-answer).